# c# How to show same video in two forms or tow video players simultaneously

Tags: c#, video, video-streaming, axwindowsmediaplayer, wmplib

I'm looking for a way to show, the video which is playing in one wmp, into another form. Basically I want to see the same video in two different forms. I looked and did a lot of searches but could't find any solution. For this reason, I will appreciate any help. 
At the moment I'm using in my form WMP to play the videos from a file but I could change the player if that is necessary. 
Thank you in advance.